# Liste de mots français avec "æ"

Tags: orthographe, diacritiques, alphabet, ligatures

Il y a 42 ans, j'ai commencé à apprendre le français à l'école mais ce n'est qu'hier que j'ai compris que je ne connaissais même pas toutes les lettres utilisées dans cette langue :-)
Entretemps, j'ai compris que les mots dans les expressions "curriculum vit**æ**" et "et c**æ**téra" contiennent cette lettre "æ", mais y a-t-il une liste de mots français qui la contiennent ?

Merci d'avance

**Question complémentaire:** J'ai toujours su que la lettre "c" se prononçait comme un [s] devant un "e", un "i" ou un "y", mais apparemment (en regardant l'expression "et cætéra"), le "c" se prononce comme [s] aussi avant le "æ", même si c'est un dérivé de la lettre "a". Est-ce que cela veut dire que l'orthographe de "et cætéra" est mauvaise et doit être modifiée en "et **ç**ætéra" (avec une cédille) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Lorsqu’un mot s’écrit avec a et e consécutifs, faut-il les écrire
> collés ou séparés ?
>
> Le caractère æ (lire a, e), avec un a et un e qui se touchent quand on
> les écrit, est **très rare** en français. Ce caractère, tiré du latin,
> peut s’appeler « a, e entrelacés » ou encore « e dans l’a ». La
> difficulté, c’est que l’on rencontre aussi des mots où a et e sont
> consécutifs mais séparés.
>
> Pour savoir si a, e s’écrivent liés ou séparés, fiez-vous à la
> prononciation. En effet, si les deux voyelles sont prononcées
> séparément, alors elles s’écrivent séparément, et même souvent avec un
> accent sur le e : *aéroport, israélien, décaèdre, gaélique, maestro,
> paella*, et cetera.
>
> En revanche, lorsque a, e se prononcent ensemble [e], il y a de fortes
> chances qu’on écrive a, e entrelacés : *curriculum vitæ, et cætera,*
> *nævus* (c’est un grain de beauté), tænia (c’est un ver parasite). Les
> mots concernés sont alors tous des emprunts, parfois tardifs, au
> latin.
>
> La difficulté est gommée pour quelques mots comportant a, e
> entrelacés, puisqu’ils possèdent une deuxième graphie avec un simple e
> accentué à la place du a, e entrelacés : *ténia* s’écrit donc aussi t, e
> accent aigu, n, i, a, *éthuse*, e accent aigu, t, h, u, s, e (c’est une
> plante toxique appelée aussi petite cigüe).
>
> On rencontre les lettres a, e, séparées, sans accent, et pourtant
> prononcées [e] dans des emprunts à d’autres langues que le latin :
> *maerl* (emprunt au breton qui désigne un type de sédiment), *reggae*, r,
> e, deux g, a, e et *sundae*, d, a, e, empruntés à l’anglais (c’est un
> dessert glacé), *spaetzle*, s, p, a, e, d’origine alémanique (ce sont
> des pâtes), et enfin *taekwondo*, t, a, e, qui nous vient du coréen.

Source : [Orthodidacte](https://www.orthodidacte.com/videos-francais/mots-qui-contiennent-ae-ou-bien-ae/#:%7E:text=Le%20caract%C3%A8re%20%C3%A6%20%28lire%20a,e%20dans%20l)

---

**EDIT 1** (après avoir vu le commentaire de l'utilisateur @Dominique).

La source ne mentionne pas "Dies iræ". Voir [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dies_ir%C3%A6.)

---

**EDIT 2**

1. Liste des 50 Mots avec "æ", en français officiel. Voir [MotsAvec](https://www.motsavec.com/search.php?m=%C3%A6&tv=4)
2. 

> En français, ce graphème se prononce [e] (é) ou [ɛ] (è) et se
> retrouve, entre autres exemples, dans des mots et locutions empruntés
> au latin, comme æschne, cæcum, nævus, præsidium (forme utilisée
> concurremment à présidium), tænia (forme utilisée concurremment à
> ténia), novæ et supernovæ (pluriels possibles de nova et supernova),
> ex æquo, curriculum vitæ ou la forme fautive et cætera ; dérivés :
> appendice iléo-cæcal (cæcum) et tæniase (tænia).
>
> On retrouve également ce graphème dans les graphies archaïques de
> certains mots français tels æther, æternel, æquité, æsthétique,
> Ægypte, Æthiopie... Dans la plupart de ces cas, l'usage remplaça l'a-e
> dans l'a par un e accent aigu.
>
> On retrouve enfin ce graphème dans des noms propres adaptés du grec
> ancien, comme Ægosthènes, ainsi que dans le prénom Lætitia, popularisé
> par Serge Gainsbourg dans sa chanson Elaeudanla Téïtéïa (dans l'album
> Gainsbourg Confidentiel).

Source : [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86)

3.

> Lettres a et e (æ) Les lettres a et e sont généralement soudées quand
> elles représentent un seul son. Cette ligature n’est toutefois pas
> obligatoire :
>
> curriculum vitæ / curriculum vitae Elles doivent rester séparées quand
> elles forment deux sons distincts :
>
> paella aérien

Source : [Termium+](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_o&page=9Evay5kkwZ68.html)

**EDIT 4** Question complémentaire

Je crois que la prononciation est la bonne puisque (voir première source) :

> En revanche, lorsque a, e se prononcent ensemble *[e]*, il y a de fortes chances qu’on écrive a, e entrelacés : curriculum vitæ, et cætera, nævus (c’est un grain de beauté), tænia (c’est un ver parasite). Les mots concernés sont alors tous des emprunts, parfois tardifs, au latin.

Comment: Je suis désolé, mais en pensant au Latin, je me rappelle un œuvre bien connu, qui ne se trouve pas dans votre liste, ce qui veut dire que votre liste n'est pas complet: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dies_ir%C3%A6.

Comment: J'ai édité ma question avec une remarque extra sur l'orthographe. Pourriez-vous y jeter un coup d'œil?

Comment: @Dominique Je viens de modifier ma réponse. J'espère que tout est bien.

Answer (score 1):

*Dies iræ* n'est pas du français, c'est du latin.

La question parle des mots en français comportant la voyelle **æ**. Pas de tous les mots, éventuellement objets de citations en français, qui la comportent. Les mots comme *tænia*, *Curriculum vitæ*, *ex æquo*, *et cætera* sont des mots empruntés au latin mais utilisés en français.

On rencontre rarement une phrase en français qui utilise le vocable *Dies Iræ*, indépendamment de la référence à l'œuvre citée. On ne dira pas en français (sauf pour faire étalage de pédanterie) :

> Pécheurs invétérés, craignez la *Dies Iræ* !

mais :

> Pécheurs invétérés, craignez la colère de Dieu !

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse. Vous donnez quelques exemples de mots en Français avec "æ" qui sont empruntés du Latin, mais vous ne donnez pas de mots avec "æ" qui ne sont pas empruntés du Latin. Vous en connaissez?

Comment: @Dominique À l'exception de noms propres (scandinaves ou autres), tous les mots comportant la ligature ***æ*** que l'on rencontre en français sont des mots latins. On les met d'ailleurs normalement en italiques justement pour ça. Cette ligature peut être remplacée par ***ae***, contrairement à la ligature ***œ*** qui est orthographique et donc toujours distincte de ***oe***.